# Avoiding duplicate Scanner input for names

Tags: java

I have a bit of code I am having trouble with at the moment. I am trying to prevent the player of a small text based game I am designing. I have written a condition to avoid a user inputting duplicate data. However I believe I am missing something but I am not sure would it would be. 
Here is my code:

```
List<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<>();
String name;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++) {
    System.out.println("Name of player " + (i + 1));
    name = scanner.next();

    if (playerList.contains(name)) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a different name!");
        i--;
    }
    playerList.add(new Player(name, STARTING_MONEY, 0));

}

return playerList;
```

I am a complete novice when it comes to Java, so I am probably missing something big but after a pretty deep search I cannot seem to find the answer. Any suggestions would be helpful thanks!

Comment: add the playerList.add(...) in an else block for your if statement. Now you add the player, whether it's a new name or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a simple `continue` to skip further execution of the loop body. Or an `else` to only add the player to the list if the name does not yet exist:

Either

```
if (playerList.contains(name)) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a different name!");
    i--;
    continue;
}
```

Or

```
if (playerList.contains(name)) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a different name!");
    i--;
} else {
    playerList.add(new Player(name, STARTING_MONEY, 0));
}
```